# Enabling scanner throw exceptions Zebra EMDK Android

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

In my app for Zebra MC330M I use EMDK: Zebra Technologies Corp:EMDK APIs:26

I have a activity that implements listener and I override onOpened function:

```
@Override
public void onOpened(EMDKManager emdkManager) {

    this.emdkManager = emdkManager;
    try {

       initializeScanner();
     } catch (ScannerException e) {

        Log.e("ON_OPENED", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
     }

}
```

And as documentation said in Link: [Basic Scanning Tutorial using Barcode API - Zebra Technologies Techdocs](http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/7-1/tutorial/tutBasicScanningAPI/)

I put in the initializeScanner function:

```
if (scanner == null) {

   // Get the Barcode Manager object
   barcodeManager = (BarcodeManager) emdkManager.getInstance(FEATURE_TYPE.BARCODE);
   // Add connection listener
   if (barcodeManager != null) {
      barcodeManager.addConnectionListener(this);
   }

   // Get default scanner defined on the device
   scanner = barcodeManager.getDevice(BarcodeManager.DeviceIdentifier.DEFAULT);
   // Add data and status listeners
   scanner.addDataListener(this);
   scanner.addStatusListener(this);
   // Hard trigger. When this mode is set, the user has to manually
  // press the trigger on the device after issuing the read call.
   scanner.triggerType = TriggerType.HARD;
   // Enable the scanner
   scanner.enable();
   startRead = true;

 }
```

But when call `scanner.enable()` it throws

> ScannerException

exception with message:

> "Failure"

But seems that error is shown only in debug mode when I try to compile my app and launch when device is standby mode or when the device is in standby for many time.

Someone else has this problem?

Comment: Hi, it might be a good idea to first test with a known working sample such as http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/7-3/samples/barcode/.  That error is quite generic so it is not possible to say from the above what the root cause could be.  For transparency, I work for Zebra.

Comment: thankyou, yes I have seen this. The problem seems to be that I have 2 activity, and if I add : singleTask in manifest activity seems works, can be this the problem?

Comment: Using the EMDK with multiple activities can be challenging - there are many questions on the Zebra developer portal about this subject.  If you want to perform scanning in different activities within your application I would strongly recommend using DataWedge rather than the EMDK.  To use the EMDK between activities it is necessary to close the EMDK from one activity before opening it in another.

Comment: thanks, actually I have only one activity with scan, the second (that actually is the first) is a Splash page, where I do only redirect.

Comment: If it is only one activity doing the scanning then that should be OK.  Another possibility is that the scanner is not being closed in your onPause() handler and so on subsequent launches it is failing - again, please see that sample app for an example implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you encountered is due to declaring 'private EMDKManager emdkManager = null;' in two activities. To fix this, you can create a class 'Constants' and declare 'static public EMDKManager emdkManager;'. Then, in both activities, replace 'emdkManager' with 'Constants.emdkManager' and 'this.emdkManager' with 'Constants.emdkManager'.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to call this function after scanning and before calling another activity :

```
public void stopEmdkManager(){
    if (this.emdkManager != null) {
        this.emdkManager.release();
        this.emdkManager = null;
    }
}
```